# Internal Server Error while creating custom content block in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I am getting Internal Server Error when I try to run my code inside a custom content block. In the node logs, I am getting below error **   window.addEventListener('message', this._receiveMessage, false);**

Below is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var BlockSDK = require('blocksdk');


var sdk = new BlockSDK();
        sdk.getContent(function (content) {
            var test = document.getElementById('#editor-container').innerHTML;
            console.log('Inside 1st Test' + test);
            test.root.innerHTML = content;

            function saveText() {
                console.log('Inside 1st saveText');
                var html = test.root.innerHTML;
                sdk.setContent(html);
                console.log('Inside HTML' + html);
                sdk.setSuperContent('This is super content: ' + html);

                sdk.getData(function (data) {
                    console.log('Inside 1st getData');
                    var numberOfEdits = data.numberOfEdits || 0;
                    sdk.setData({
                        numberOfEdits: numberOfEdits + 1
                    });
                });
            }
            test.on('text-change', saveText);
        });

app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`) });
```

And here is my HTML,

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="#editor-Container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me with the issue I am facing?

I have also attached my logs below:

@Johannes Schapdick I am getting this error while building the project. I have attached the logs as well.

```
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390931+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/blocksdk/blocksdk.js:28
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390947+00:00 app[web.1]:    window.addEventListener('message', this._receiveMessage, false);
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390949+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390950+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390952+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: window is not defined
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390954+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new SDK (/app/node_modules/blocksdk/blocksdk.js:28:2)
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390955+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:7:11)
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390957+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390958+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390960+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390961+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390963+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390964+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390966+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
2018-12-17T11:52:13.390968+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: I dont know if it is a problem but your div id is written with Container in your html while your code tries to get the container with a lowercase c.

Comment: @Johannes Schapdick I have edited my question to display the logs as well